# How to capture the port number from this `lsof -F` output using awk (or something better)?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, lsof

I've got output coming from `lsof -F` that looks like this:

```
p7646
g7646
R8300
csocat
u1000
Labe
f3
au
l
tIPv4
G0x80002;0x0
d640391
o0t0
PTCP
n*:51352
TST=LISTEN
TQR=0
TQS=0
```

I am trying to capture the value `51352`, which is a bound port I'm interested in knowing.

I'm close in that I can get the `n*:51352` value with this:

```
awk '/^n/ { print $1 }'
```

and can actually get the exact `51352` value I need with two separate `awk`s:

```
awk '/^n/ { print $1 }' | awk -F':' '{print $2}'
```

but is there a better way, either a single-command `awk` or a cleaner non-`awk` solution?

There should only ever be one line starting with `n*` so I don't need to worry about handling multiple lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combine the two:

```
awk -F: '/^n\*:/ {print $2}'
```

Answer (score 3):

Other possibilities:

- sed

  ```
  sed -n 's/^n\*:\(.*\)/\1/p'
  ```
- grep

  ```
  grep -Po '^n\*:\K.*'
  ```